# Notepad++ || How do add to beginning of every line NOT containing a specific string?

Tags: notepad++

I need to add |||||| to the beginning of every line that does NOT contain the following date/time format:

```
 24, 2016||3:45am||
```

More specifically, every line that does NOT contain the following regular expressions string:

```
 \d{1,2}, 201\d{1}\|\|\d{1,2}:\d{2}am\|\|
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is derived from the negative look-around answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

`^((?!\d{1,2}, 201\d{1}\|\|\d{1,2}:\d{2}am\|\|).)*$`

To find and replace the text, you'll need to wrap the whole thing in brackets:

`(^((?!\d{1,2}, 201\d{1}\|\|\d{1,2}:\d{2}am\|\|).)*$)`

Then in the replace field, put in `|||||| $1`

Comment: That did indeed match all of the lines I wanted it to. Thanks for that. What do I put in the replace with box though? I was trying \|\|\|\|\|\|\1 and it doesn't seem to work properly. I want to add in the entire line that it was matching, and have |||||| before it.